# How to create XML output in ColdFusion?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm working on my project where I have to output XML document from ColdFusion query. I created my page but that does not work for me. If anyone can help with this please let me know. Here is my code:

```
<!--- Query the database and get the StaffId, FirstName, LastName in Staff table. --->
<cfquery name="myquerry" datasource="employee">
    Select StaffId,FirstName,LastName
    From Staff
    Order by LastName,FirstName
</cfquery>

<!--- Create an XML documnet. --->
<cfxml variable="mydoc">
    <livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name">
        <staff>
            <cfoutput query="myquery">
                <id>#StaffId#</id>
                <first>#FirstName#</first>
                <last>#LastName#</last>
            </cfoutput>
        </staff>
    </livelookup>
</cfxml>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work for me"? What is the result of the code above? How is it different than what you expected?

Comment: After I run this code I just get this: Select StaffId,FirstName,LastName From Staff Order by LastName,FirstName #StaffId# #FirstName# #LastName#

Comment: First, your `cfquery`'s name does not match your `cfoutput` query argument. Secondly, in your `cfoutput` the nodes `id`, `first`, and `last` will just be duplicated in the `staff` node for each row of the query. I'm assuming (since you don't say what the output *should* be) that these nodes should have a parent inside the `cfoutput`

Comment: Is the output you defined what you see in the browser? If so, look at the source to see the actual XML

Comment: I use this XML output for Livelookup search.

Comment: If you *lterally* get "Select StaffId,FirstName,LastName From Staff Order by LastName,FirstName #StaffId# #FirstName# #LastName#" as the output in your browser then your server is misconfigured and does not even process the CFML.

Comment: Yes that is what I got for my output.

Comment: Yes I have ColdFusion installed.

Comment: If you have CF installed, then @Tomalak is right - your server is misconfigured. Research how to configure your webserver to process ColdFusion (.cfm) files. If you can't get a simple CF page to process, then this whole question is invalid. In the future, being more specific about how your code "does not work for you" would save a lot of time and headache for the rest of us.

Comment: @user3023588 You need to update your question to contain any new information you have shared in the comments; don't just put it in a comment: the object of the exercise with the comments is for US to advise you what clarifications *your question* needs for it to be answerable. You also need to have a think about the whole "how to ask a question so you can reasonably expect someone to be able to answer it" thing. You need to read this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, and follow its guidance when asking a question (or rewording this one)